# Fancybox responds on second click and doesn't switch to next image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I've been using fancybox quite a lot, and as far as I see I haven't done anything wrong. The images respond on the SECOND click, which is quite weird and the next/previous image doesn't work.

Html code:

```
<div id="fotobox">
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.sensrealestate.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/fallout-wp8-800x6002.jpeg" ><img src="images/_userfiles/pictures/foto1.jpg" alt="image"/></a>
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.sensrealestate.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/fallout-wp8-800x6002.jpeg" ><img src="images/_userfiles/pictures/foto1.jpg" alt="image"/></a>
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.sensrealestate.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/fallout-wp8-800x6002.jpeg" ><img src="images/_userfiles/pictures/foto1.jpg" alt="image"/></a>
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.sensrealestate.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/fallout-wp8-800x6002.jpeg" ><img src="images/_userfiles/pictures/foto1.jpg" alt="image"/></a>
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.sensrealestate.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/fallout-wp8-800x6002.jpeg" ><img src="images/_userfiles/pictures/foto1.jpg" alt="image"/></a>
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.sensrealestate.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/fallout-wp8-800x6002.jpeg" ><img src="images/_userfiles/pictures/foto1.jpg" alt="image"/></a>
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.sensrealestate.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/fallout-wp8-800x6002.jpeg" ><img src="images/_userfiles/pictures/foto1.jpg" alt="image"/></a>
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.sensrealestate.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/fallout-wp8-800x6002.jpeg" ><img src="images/_userfiles/pictures/foto1.jpg" alt="image"/></a>
                </div>
```

And jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
```

What can possibly be going wrong here?

I've putted my project live at http://www.warrebuysse.be/test
Click on "band" in the navigation, and you'll see.

Any thoughts? Need to get this finished before dawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link href="css/libs/jquery.fancybox.cssu" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                                 <!---  ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing your link to the fancybox.css file first.  Currently you have it linking here:

> http://www.warrebuysse.be/test/css/libs/jquery.fancybox.cssu

Remove the u at the end of the link.

Comment: Incredibly stupid. Have been searching for a while here. Quite retarded. Thanks! :)